# MySQL select from two tables where one column contain 2 variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables :

The first table is `tbl_ccompany`

```
db_id   db_cname
 1         xxx
 2         yyy
```

The second table `tbl_marketing`

```
db_mid db_name db_ccompany
1       ggg     1,2
```

In `tbl_marketing` db_ccompany contain the id of the first table

I want to select the db_cname to print 
the out put will be like this

```
1  ggg xxx,yyy
```

I try the left join between this two table but only i receive the first name

```
select 
marketing.*,
ccompany.db_cname
from tbl_marketing as marketing
left join tbl_ccompany as ccompany
on
marketing.db_ccompany=ccompany.db_id
```

How can i join the tables and have the output i want ?

Comment: Let's see some of the code you have so far so we can better help you identify what's wrong.

Comment: @AdamA please check above

Comment: You should re-design your database. Better to keep association of `tbl_ccompany` and `tbl_marketing` in a different table, rather then putting them comma separated in the same table.

Comment: why did you create such db desing ? why do you use comma for each record? that's not a good practice.

Comment: @Badiparmagi i use comma because i store many value in this field what you suggest ?!

Comment: Check the [FIND_IN_SET() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). But you shouldn't store your data this way.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel any suggestion to store my data

Comment: @mohamadmohamad See [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT db_mid,db_name,GROUP_CONCAT(db_cname) FROM tbl_marketing LEFT JOIN tbl_ccompany on db_id=db_ccompany WHERE db_ccompany in(1,2)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, please add a short description of what your command does and why it solves the initial problem.

Comment: Mahamad wants this result in query : 

" I want to select the db_cname to print the out put will be like this

1  ggg xxx,yyy"

So I have added "db_mid,db_name,GROUP_CONCAT(db_cname)" in SELECT field, And We need to fetch result WHERE "db_ccompany in(1,2)"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

Database Structure:

```
create table tbl_ccompany (
db_id int,
db_cname text );

insert into tbl_ccompany values (1,'xxx');
insert into tbl_ccompany values (2,'yyy');

create table tbl_marketing (
db_mid int ,
db_name text,
db_ccompany text
);

insert into tbl_marketing values (1,'ggg','1,2');
```

Query:

```
select db_mid, db_name, group_concat(db_cname) 
from tbl_ccompany tc , tbl_marketing tm
where find_in_set(tc.db_id,tm.db_ccompany)
```

Reference: 
http://amitbrothers.blogspot.in/2014/03/mysql-split-comma-separated-list-into.html

Comment: @mohamadmohamad Is it helpful ?